# customer/address/ route 404

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, 404

When I view the route : http://url.co.uk/customer/address/ i get a 404.

My local.xml looks like:

```
<customer_account>
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account</name><path>customer/account/</path><label>Dashboard</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>account_edit</name><path>customer/account/edit/</path><label>Information</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>address_book</name><path>customer/address/</path><label>Address Book</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="newsletter"><name>newsletter</name><path>newsletter/manage/</path><label>Newsletter Subscription</label></action>
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="review"><name>reviews</name><path>review/customer</path><label>My Product Reviews</label></action>
        </block>
 </customer_account>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: code looks ok. does your other customer account pages working?

Comment: All other links work as expected.

Comment: http://url.co.uk/customer/address/new/ did you try this?

Comment: 404 aswell unfortunately

Comment: app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AddressController.php just look this file is exist in your setup or see if any module override Mage_Customer_AddressController class.

Comment: No modules override that class.

Comment: I have overridden Mage_Customer_AccountController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've overridden Mage_Customer_AccountController which was the issue to the 404, I haven't diagnosed the exact issue, but the issue stems from the overwrite.